# Getting "EOFError" in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting EOFError not in my terminal but in Coursera's terminal.
in my system it shows expected output but the coursera is not accepting it

python3

```
#Uses python3

import sys

def largest_number(a):
     #write your code here
     l = len(a)
     for i in range(0,l):
          m = max(a)
          print(m,sep="",end ="")
          a.remove(m)

     return 0



if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    for i in range(0,n):
        data = list(map(int,input().split()))
        largest_number(data)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "largest_number.py", line 20, in <module>
    data = list(map(int,input().split()))
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Comment: Please show us your input versus Coursera's input. It's difficult to guess where the problem lies without a reproducible example.

Comment: Sample 2.
Input:
5
9 4 6 1 9
Output:
99641

Sample 3.
Input:
3
23 39 92
Output:
923923

Comment: the previous one is coursera's input and output. my code shows the same output in both terminal. it shows correct output in Coursera's terminal as well but at the end it shows the above error

Comment: as I know Coursera and similar portals you don't need `for` loop beause all numbers are in one line and one `input().split()` gives you all data at once. Use `print(data)` to see if you get all numbers in first loop.

Answer (score 0):

I will guess: as I know portals with challenges they put all numbers in one line so you can get all values using only one `input`

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # get `n` but I will not use it later
    input()

    # get all numbers at once
    data = list(map(int, input().split()))
    largest_number(data)
```

Other languages may need `n` because they may read numbers one by one and they have to know how many numbers are in line.